# Visual studio code python extension error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
Activating extension 'ms-python.python' failed: command 'python.viewOutput' already exists.
workbench.desktop.main.js:2350 Cannot activate the 'Pylance' extension because its dependency 'Python' failed to activate
```

I tried to edit a python file with vscode and it shows extension activation failed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try disabling all other python extensions in VSCode. I had the same issue because a different Python VS extension was conflicting with the official extension. Here's [a link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9578) that might be able to help you in more detail.

It's hard to give you a more specific answer for this type of question without knowing more about your setup.

EDIT: Look at the comment thread on this answer if you need more details

Comment: what do you mean "setup" ?

Comment: (ie. Whether you have other extensions installed, version of python, whether your ~/.vscode/extensions/ is all configured properly, what your source map looks like, etc) But definitely try just reinstalling, it's often just an issue with a bad file.

Comment: i tried reinstalling several times im having this issue for 1 month

Comment: i tried all the things i can but  still same error

Comment: Do you have any other python extensions installed?

Comment: Also, don't simply uninstall, you must manually remove all files belonging to the extension you want to delete from ~/.vscode/extensions/

Comment: no i dont have any python extensions except main

Comment: now it show's some other error https://nekobin.com/tiyananiqe

Comment: Do you have python installed?

Comment: yes python is installed https://pasteboard.co/KdqsNnN.png

Comment: The traceback says that geecode.geecode-python may be on your device. The official python extension is ms-python.python

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your VSCode screen, including the terminal? Also include the extensions tab (four boxes button on the left of the screen).

Comment: You have over 10 extensions installed. You need to disable all of the python related ones except the ms-python.python. That was my original answer.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had to disable "isort" by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

You should go through standard troubleshooting procedures like uninstalling and reinstalling ms-python.python. Check if you have multiple python extensions installed and that you only have one installed. [This might give you a bit more detail.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9578)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on remote.

In addition to the jupyter extension, I also installed the `pylance` extension (on remote); that worked. Nothing else did.